# phpinfo() shows MySQL, PMA shows MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am really confused about that

There is a phpinfo() output:

**MySQL Support**   enabled

**Client API version**  5.5.40

**MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE**   external

And the phpMyAdmin shows:

**Server type**: MariaDB

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, but does that mean that MDB **IS** a MySQL database? Why phpinfo does not provide any information about MariaDB?

I am not sure if php is correctly configured on my hosting server, either not sure how to check it.

Comment: Yes, they're compatible. The phpinfo page thus only shows the available support for the mysql-compatible server protocol.

Comment: Well, thanks. I guess it should be an answer so I will be able to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not necessarily a 1:1 correspondence between web servers running php and database servers running MySQL (or a different kind of database).  The two things, even if running on the same system, are not connected or aware of each other, unless *your php code* specifically connects to the MySQL Server, and it isn't unheard of for a web app to connect to more than one MySQL Server.

So to expect the php info script to know anything about the MySQL Server is to expect the wrong thing.

> Client API version 5.5.40

This means php has the MySQL client module that shipped with MySQL Server 5.5.40 and so is fully compatible with any MySQL Server up to and including version 5.5.40, and for the most part should also work with newer versions.

MariaDB is, for most purposes, fully compatible with MySQL Server, and the MySQL client library used by php.

Oracle owns MySQL.  MariaDB is based on MySQL, and includes performance improvements of its own as well as some that were integrated from a third product, Percona Server, which is also MySQL compatible.  MariaDB and Percona both are essentially drop-in replacements for MySQL.  They look and act and communicate just like MySQL (with exceptions not relevant to the average user) and php doesn't know the difference, or care.  A fourth variant is Amazon Aurora, also MySQL compatible, but some legacy capabilities are removed and others enhanced, in the interest of very high performance.  Aurora is only available as a cloud service; the others can all be installed locally.

But php is only showing you its capability of connecting to MySQL -- not info about the MySQL server itself.